# jQuery showAllComments toggle - with true/false variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

**Hello I have a comments system, where it loads maximum 10 comments.
I use JQuery AJAX post to send the entered data and then fetch results.**

Now I've added a button to load ALL messages, that button will send another POST and the post will lead to a function in PHP that loads all result without **LIMIT 10.**

*Everything's great, but I have alittle problem.*

If I click the load all messages button, **it will add ALL messages + not remove the other 10.**

That's an *easy fix*, I just delete the other one when it's processing.
But then when I click the load all messages button, it will not show all messages, it will show 10 again.

**That's because javascript is performing the load messages process over and over.**

**Therefore I need to do something like this:**

```
if (loadAll == false) {
     load10 messages
} else {
     load all messages
}
```

**But my question is:**

How can I do this? I MUST define the function loadAll as a false (which is default), and then I can do:

```
$("#loadall").click(function() {
     loadAll = true;
});
```

And before it I can add:

```
var loadAll = true;
```

or just

```
 loadAll = true;
```

but when the javascript will process, the definition of loadAll = false will overwrite the true after you click that link, so the all comments won't load..

**Question**

How can I make it not overwrite the FALSE with TRUE on click of $("#loadall").click() ?
So it will delete the 10 comments, and then load ALL comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another variable that says

```
var loadingData = false;
```

And modify the variable to true when ever you do an ajax request. 
When request is complete move it back to false.
Check for both variables when you start to fetch data before you do ajax requests.

EDIT:

```
var loadingData = false;
var loadAll = false;

function loadMessageFunc{
    if(!loadAll && !loadingData) {
        loadingData = true;
        //Get Data Here
        //On Result
        ...
        loadingData = false;
    }
}

function loadAllFunc{
    if(!loadingData) {
         loadAll = true;
         loadingData = true;
         //Get All Data Here
         //On Result
         ...
         loadAll = true; //If you want to stop load message calls after one load all call
         loadingData = false;
    }
}
```

This will ensure both are not getting called at the same time. And you can clear / load data accordingly.